# Question about eigenvalues of polynomial of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know if $A$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $f(A)$ has an eigenvalue $f(\lambda)$, where $f$ is a polynomial defined on the same field as $A$.

To clarify my question, I use an example. Suppose $A_{3 \times 3}$ has eigenvalue $(-1,-1,1)$ and $f=x^2$, I know $A^2$ has eigenvalue $\mu=1$, will the Algebraic multiplicity of $\mu$ equals to $3$? How to prove it? Are the results still true for more general cases?

Comment: Yes, it's true in general. A quick and dirty way to prove it is to triangularise $A$ over the algebraic closure of the ground field.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, yes, $1$ has an algebraic multiplicity of $3$ in $A^2$.

Nothing special is going on here; $A^2$ has characteristic polynomial $(\lambda-1)^3$ (because its eigenvalues are now $1$, $1$, and $1$), so $1$ has algebraic multiplicity $3$.

I would hesitate to say there's necessarily a more general result. Like, I guess if $\lambda_0,-\lambda_0$ ($\lambda_0>0$) are real eigenvalues of $A$ with multiplicities $m,m'$ respectively, then $\lambda_0^2$ has multiplicity $m+m'$ in $A^2$, but I'm not sure if that's the kind of result you're looking for. Certainly not very general, but I'd be hesitant to consider any statements on multiplicity with how much $f$ could vary.

But the same "obvious" pattern I mentioned at the outset does hold: if $f$ is a polynomial and $\lambda_i$ the eigenvalues of $A$ (not necessarily distinct), then

$$p_A(\lambda) = \prod_i (\lambda - \lambda_i)$$

is $A$'s characteristic polynomial, then

$$p_{f(A)}(\lambda) = \prod_i \Big( \lambda - f(\lambda_i) \Big)$$

How this affects the multiplicities will just ultimately depend on $f$ and the $\lambda_i$, but at least in principle this should be easy to determine.